# Syntax error in local variable inside trigger declaration

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, user-variables

I have the following store procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_ordenes`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE record CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT ordenes.idorden, ordenes.idafiliado 
            FROM ordenes, afiliados 
            WHERE afiliados.idafiliado = ordenes.idafiliado;

    OPEN record;
    REPEAT
        FETCH record INTO @id_orden, @id_afil_viejo;

        INSERT INTO afil2(nombre, apellido, documento) 
            (SELECT nombre, apellido, documento
                FROM afiliados 
                WHERE idafiliado = @id_afil_viejo);

        SET @last_id = (SELECT id FROM afil2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);

        UPDATE ordenes 
        SET afil2 = @last_id,
            ordenes.idafiliado = NULL
        WHERE ordenes.idafiliado = @id_afil_viejo
              AND ordenes.idorden = @orden_id;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;
END
```

for some reason, I get an syntax error at line `FETCH record INTO @id_orden, @id_afil_viejo;`

in [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) I can run `SELECT id, data INTO @x, @y FROM test.t1 LIMIT 1;`. 
Is the problem in the use of the `FETCH`? or What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[`FETCH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fetch.html) (which grabs the next record from, and advances, a cursor) is *not* the same as [`SELECT ... INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) (which only works with queries that returns a single record).

`FETCH` can *only* fetch into [local variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-program-variables.html) (which have no `@` prefix but must be [`DECLARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/declare.html)d at the start of your stored program), whereas `SELECT ... INTO` can also fetch into [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html) (which do have a `@` prefix and are not `DECLARE`d).

You must therefore `DECLARE` a local variable into which your records will be `FETCH`ed:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_ordenes`()
BEGIN

    DECLARE id_orden BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 5;  -- as appropriate
    DECLARE id_afiv_viejo VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL;  -- as appropriate

    DECLARE record CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT ordenes.idorden, ordenes.idafiliado 
            FROM ordenes, afiliados 
            WHERE afiliados.idafiliado = ordenes.idafiliado;

    OPEN record;
    REPEAT
        FETCH record INTO id_orden, id_afil_viejo;

        INSERT INTO afil2(nombre, apellido, documento) 
            (SELECT nombre, apellido, documento
                FROM afiliados 
                WHERE idafiliado = id_afil_viejo);

        SET @last_id = (SELECT id FROM afil2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);

        UPDATE ordenes 
        SET afil2 = @last_id,
            ordenes.idafiliado = NULL
        WHERE ordenes.idafiliado = id_afil_viejo
              AND ordenes.idorden = id_orden;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;
END
```

All that said, your sproc is very unsafe (a race hazard exists between the first `INSERT` statement and the `SET` that follows) and an incredibly unwieldy way of doing something that ought to be much simpler.

Comment: I didn't found a better way to get the id of inserted row in `afil2` but  I'm all ears! :)

Comment: I'm newbie in store procedures.